# Python - How to handle both int aswell as gmpy / mpz without function overloading?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm very new to python and I have to implement a few algorithms. To achieve better performance for big numbers (> 1024 bit), I would like to use gmpy2/mpz - but I would still like to support normal python integers aswell.

As Python lacks function overloading, I'm wondering how this can best be achieved.

```
if(a.__class__.__name__ == 'mpz'):
    a = gmpy2.floor(x/8)
else:
    a = floor(x/8)
```

Is there a better way to avoid this duality?

Comment: Pretty sure that `gmpy2.floor` will handle both cases. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `x/8` will be interpreted first and will result in a standard Python float type. This will cause a loss of precision for large numbers since the float type only has 53 bits of precision.

If you are working with integers, you should use the floor division operator `//`. No conversion to floating point is needed. The approach automatically works with Python integers and the mpz type.

```
>>> 123456789//256
482253
>>> gmpy2.mpz(123456789)//256
mpz(482253)
>>> 123456789//gmpy2.mpz(256)
mpz(482253)
>>> gmpy2.mpz(123456789)//gmpy2.mpz(256)
mpz(482253)
```

**To answer the question in the comment...**

If you are working with large integer inputs and want integer results, I would avoid floating point operations and work entirely with integers. The following snippet should work with both Python integers and the mpz type and is not limited by the precision of the Python float type.

```
q,r = divmod(123456789,256)
q += bool(r)
```

`q` will have the desired result.

Comment: Ah thanks a lot! May I ask, as floor was just one example, how would I best handle the `gmpy2.ceil()`? Cause as far as I know, there is no `//` equivalent for ceiling.